# How to fetch and edit embeds in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to fetch embeds and scroll between them . Here is what I tried doing:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self,ctx):
    
        chan = self.bot.get_channel(746339276983238677)
        message1 = await chan.fetch_message(761267709438328904)
        message2 = await chan.fetch_message(761267744721076265)
        message3 = await chan.fetch_message(761267778639495168)

        page1= message1.embeds[0]
        
        page2= message2.embeds[0]
        
        page3= message3.embeds[0]



        contents = [page1,page2,page3]
        pages = 3
        cur_page = 1
        message = await ctx.send(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")

        await message.add_reaction("◀️")
        await message.add_reaction("▶️")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

                if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                    cur_page += 1
                    await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                    cur_page -= 1
                    await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.delete()
                break
```

It doesn't send the embeds. it sends this:

[image]

How do I fetch embeds and send them and then how to I edit them?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an embed, you're supposed to use

```
await ctx.send(embed=embed_variable)
```

attaching it to the message. You're sending the actual embed instance where it expects a string. So in your case, you should use

```
await ctx.send(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
```

Afterwards, you can edit them like you want to, using the usual embed methods & attributes (`add_field`, `set_footer`, ...).